# Restrict jQuery draggable items from overlapping/colliding with sibling elements

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-draggable, containment

I need to use jQuery UI to restrict the containment area for draggable object with some additional restriction. I need prevent the draggable element from overlapping with other elements within the same container. I need to allow movement in "moveInHere" area but not "butNotHere" area. Is it possible?

```
<div id="moveInHere">

    <div id="dragMe"> </div>

    <div id="butNotHere"> </div>

</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    $("#dragMe").draggable({
        containment: "#moveInHere"
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**Edit: New Solution**

I found a plugin for this called [JQuery UI Draggable Collision](http://sourceforge.net/projects/jquidragcollide/). Using this, implementing your desired functionality becomes trivial. See the following jsFiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/q3x8w03y/1/ (This uses version 1.0.2 of JQuery UI Draggable Collision, along with JQuery 1.7.2 and JQueryUI 1.1.18.)

Here is the code:

```
$("#dragMe").draggable({
    obstacle: "#butNotHere",
    preventCollision: true,
    containment: "#moveInHere"
});
```

​

**Old Solution**

The following should work. It has a glitch, though. Once the divs collide, you have to "regrab" the div you are dragging, which can be a little annoying. Perhaps someone else will know how to fix this this. You can see my jsFiddle example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/MrAdE/8/): http://jsfiddle.net/MrAdE/8/

```
var prevOffset, curOffset;
$("#dragMe").draggable({
    drag: function(e,ui) {
        prevOffset= curOffset;
        curOffset= $.extend({},ui.offset);
        return true;
    }
});

$("#butNotHere").droppable({
    greedy: true,
    over: function(e,ui) {
        ui.helper.offset(curOffset= prevOffset).trigger("mouseup");
    },
    tolerance: "touch"
});​
```

Comment: +1 Clever to use `droppable`'s `over` event to trigger a `mouseup`.

Comment: Do you know if your new solution is compatible with JQuery 1.10?  I'm getting errors.

Comment: This jsfiddle does not work anymore. Answer should be updated with the details of versions etc

Comment: @Kukeltje JSFiddle removed the third party files I'd uploaded for the example. Looks like you can't upload third part files any more, so I embedded them in the JavaScript section. Here's the new example: http://jsfiddle.net/q3x8w03y/1/ I'll update the answer with versions.

Comment: New solution will not work with jQuery UI 1.10 and greater

Comment: in old solution ,, is there anything we can do in `out` method ......because it stucks after it touches the obstacle

Answer (score 7):

This took me quite a bit of fiddling.  Basically I created a `droppable` on the element you want to avoid, then set a boolean when the drag is over it.  I then use that in an undocumented revert function override to cancel the drop.  It only works if `#dragMe` is fully over `#butNotHere`:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var shouldCancel = false;
    $('#dragMe').draggable({
        containment: '#moveInHere',
        revert: function(){
            if (shouldCancel) {
                shouldCancel = false;
                return true;
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        }
    });
    $('#butNotHere').droppable({
        over: function(){
            shouldCancel = true;
        },
        out: function(){
            shouldCancel = false;
        }
    });
});
```

Check out the working demo and feel free to play with it: http://jsfiddle.net/H59Nb/31/