# Prevent draggable item to be drop over specific element

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

I have created multiple hotspots which are draggable, but my problem is in same container there is one section; in that section I don't want to drop draggable element. Please check below snippet.

```js
$(".draggable").draggable({
  containment: ".container",
 
});
```

```css
.container{
  width:100%;
  position:relative;
  height:300px;
  background:#eaeaea;
}
label{display:inline-block;}
.draggable {
    position: absolute!important;
    min-width: 85px;
    border: none!important;
    background: transparent!important;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    z-index:1;
}
.draggable label:first-child{
  background:blue;
  border:1px solid green;
  width:10px;
  height:10px;
  border-radius:50%;
  float:left;
  margin-top:3px;
  margin-right:10px;
}

.draggable label:last-child {
    overflow: hidden;
    max-width: 100px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
    padding: 5px;
    background: #9afff1;
}

.section {
    position: absolute;
    width: 240px;
    height: 100px;
    background: #dfbaba;
    bottom: 0;
    border: 1px solid #d5a1a1;
}
```

```html
<link href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div class="container">
  <div class="draggable">
    <label></label>
    <label>hotspot1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable">
    <label></label>
    <label>hotspot2</label>
  </div>
  <div class="draggable">
    <label></label>
    <label>hotspot3</label>
  </div>
  
  <div class="section">
  </div>
</div>
```

In above snippet hotspots are droppable on that red background section. How to prevent that? Please check below image for better understandig.

[image]

Also on drop how to check two hotspots are overlapped on not? If two hotsots are overlapping each other then I want to change class which will change direction of hotspot. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can achieve this by without any plugin like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(".draggable").draggable({
      containment: ".container" ,             
      stop: function(event,ui ) {                             
        if($(this).draggable('option','revert'))
            $(this).draggable('option','revert', false );           
          },
    });
    //this will prevent any collision
       $(".draggable" ).droppable({
            drop: function( event, ui ) {
            ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', true );                     
            }
          });       
       // this will prevent drop on section     
       $( ".section" ).droppable({
              drop: function( event, ui ) {       
            ui.draggable.draggable( 'option', 'revert', true );         
              }
        });    

});
```

Comment: I have implemented your suggested code it works fine only problem is some part of draggable element overlapp on section then it is not revert back. please check fiddle https://fiddle.jshell.net/2hvcjvf3/2/

Comment: Thanks but this is not a problem for me. Please check image for understanding https://s24.postimg.org/c12wbc6qd/Capture.png

Comment: In above image element not revert even if some part of it is in section

Comment: Though it is not an elegant solution, but a work around could be to put this section in a parent div with bit larger attributes of width and height and then put that in droppable check. May be some CSS can help us too.

Comment: please check what I mean though you need to tweak things a bit https://fiddle.jshell.net/2hvcjvf3/5/

Answer (score 1):

you should use an additional plugin to `preventCollision` with a sibling

see here > https://github.com/dsbaars/jq-ui-draggable-collision

or here > https://sourceforge.net/projects/jquidragcollide/

your final code would be

```
$(".draggable").draggable({
    containment: ".container",
    obstacle: ".section",
    preventCollision:true


});
```

see more on this subject on SO > [Restrict jQuery draggable items from overlapping/colliding with sibling elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452185/restrict-jquery-draggable-items-from-overlapping-colliding-with-sibling-elements)

hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for solution. I will try this. :)

Comment: let me know if it helps

Comment: Please tell me it will work with jquery-ui-1.12.1.min.js? While implementing I am getting error "Cannot read property 'options' of undefined"

Comment: check the instalation guide from the first link

Copy jquery-ui-draggable-collision.js or any specific or minified version of jquery-ui-draggable-collision(-x.x.x)(.min).js into your javascript directory
Make sure that jquery 1.10.1 or later is somewhere accessible
Make sure that jqueryui 10.4 or later is somewhere accessible
Make sure that jquery-collision 1.0.1 or later is somewhere accessible

Comment: Yes I am trying the same. I don't know what is wrong in my installation. Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0):

You can try on stop check if draggable position is over restricted area and if it is - set revert to true, and on start make it false again