# How to restrict draggable element into particular element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

In JQuery UI, I am trying to restrict draggable element into particular elements which are present inside the container (`.container`).

Even I have tried with `containment` as array of values it is working but in my case I will be unaware of the `.container` height and width. Please suggest me which will the right approach to do this one.

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="restricted-field-1">should be restricted here</div>
  <div class="dragme">DRAG ME</div>
  <div class="restricted-field-2">should be restricted here</div>
</div>

$(".dragme").draggable({
    containment: ".container"
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/v28r9v3r/2/)

Comment: Are you trying to limit the dragging within the white background area?

Comment: This post might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452185/restrict-jquery-draggable-items-from-overlapping-colliding-with-sibling-elements

Comment: This post might be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452185/restrict-jquery-draggable-items-from-overlapping-colliding-with-sibling-elements

Comment: Thank you for reply yes I'm trying to limit within the white background area @karthika

Answer (score 1):

You can move the `.container` div to wrap `.dragme`, remove `position: relative` of `.container` and set following style changes.

```
body {
  position:relative;
}
```

Modify as follows.

```
.container {
    position: absolute;
    height: 362px;
}
.restricted-field-2 {
    top: 400px;
}
```

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v28r9v3r/8/) is the jsfiddle link.

**Edited:**

There are options in jquery draggable to set `x-axis` and `y-axis` positions for the containment and we need to calculate based on our requirement.

[Here](https://jsfiddle.net/v28r9v3r/9/) is the updated js fiddle link.

Comment: Yes this will work but actually I need to do changes in jquery ui side(scripting side). Thank you

Comment: I have added updated js fiddle link with changes in scripting side alone as you mentioned. Hope that helps.

Comment: Yes this works, but the thing is here I don't know the exact height and width of container and restricted elements.
Thank you

Comment: You can calculate the width and height using width() and height(). Fiddle link here: https://jsfiddle.net/v28r9v3r/12/

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(".dragme").draggable({
 containment: ".mini"
});
```

```css
.container{
  position:relative;
  width: 500px;
  height: 400px;
  background: #FFF;
}

.dragme{
  width: 100px;
  cursor: move;
  background: black;  
  color:white;
  text-align:center;
}
.restricted-field-1{
  width:480px;
  background: silver;
  padding:10px;
  user-select:none;
  height: 20px;
}
.restricted-field-2{
  position:absolute;
  width:480px;
  bottom:0;  
  padding:10px;
  background: silver; 
  user-select:none;
  height:20px;

  
}
.mini{
  position: absolute;
  top: 40px;
  left: 0px;
  bottom: 40px;
  
  width: 100%;

  
 }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="restricted-field-1">should be restricted here</div>
  <div class="mini">
   <div class="dragme">DRAG ME</div>
  </div>
 
  <div class="restricted-field-2">should be restricted here</div>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thank you for reply, actually I don't have to create new element inside the container.