# Avoid draggables overlap in JQuery UI

Tags: javascript, jquery

How can I prevent the divs from overlapping?

```js
$("#one").draggable({ containment: 'document' });
$("#two").draggable({ containment: 'document' });
```

```css
.draggable { 
    margin:0px;
    padding:20px 5px 10px 5px;
    float:left;
    cursor:grab; 
    width:60px;
    font-size:40px;
    color:white;
    background-color: #2e5888;
    opacity:0.6;
    border-radius:5px;
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid rgb(38, 20, 102);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

<div id="one" class="draggable">
 one
</div>
      
<div id="two" class="draggable">
 two
</div>
```

Comment: Have you seen: [Restrict jQuery draggable items from overlapping/colliding with sibling elements](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11452185)

Comment: @NickParsons thanks for the link but it does not work with other draggables..

Comment: Does this help you: http://jsfiddle.net/bogatyr77/b5a84smx/1/

Comment: @BernhardBeatus why don't you post an answer with that info so I can check it? I think it would be good for people looking for this info.

Comment: Thanks for that advise. I will make an runnable  answer.